# Store user Input in ArrayList and remove it again

Tags: java

I'm starting to make an ATM machine and are bumped into a problem.
It must be possible to create and delete new accounts to the user, and
user should be able to get a total of all his various accounts.
I imagine this must be done with an ArrayList, and a scanner that allows the user to enter their accounts. But since I am fairly new to this game, I have trouble connecting with these requirements of an ArrayList.
I hope you understand my problem and have the opportunity to help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So basically you want somebody to repeat to you what every tutorial about `ArrayList` or the Java API could tell you as well?

Comment: Or if you can give me a link to such tutorial would be fine. I have just searched around google for tutorials or other questions about this, but i couldn't find anything near my requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this would answer your question...

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html

Comment: Very usefull link, thank you very much. I have now tried to write some code with my requirements. But i got a problem. My ArrayList is working fine, but i will like to make it proceed outside the for-loop i have created, if pressing "n", and continue ind the for-loop if pressing "y". What do I do wrong?
How do i inset my code??